# How can I find which kubernetes certificate has expired?

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have a `kubeadm` installed kubernetes cluster. Recently it stopped working. `kubelet` is running but seems stuck in initialization phases. I think the root cause is this recurring log in `kube-apiserver`:

```
1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="[x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2021-06-02T13:18:50Z is after 2021-05-29T15:48:22Z
```

So there is a certificate issue, also `kubectl` is failing with `unauthorized`. The thing is, `kubeadm certs check-expiration` seems happy, and I even manually checked a few yaml config files (base64 decoded certificates, and run them through openssl to check the date). Nevertheless, I asked kubeadm to renew all certificates and rebooted everything, to no effect.

Any idea how I can identify which certificate exactly has expired ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[acknowledgment and reference] I was helped by a kubernetes' dev [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/102556)*

The expired certificate was `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-2020-*.pem`. The certificates in `/var/lib/kublet/pki/` are not handled by `kubeadm cert` but by `kubelet` itself, so it's supposed to be renewed automatically, but for some reason this didn't happen as planned for us. The `kubelet-client-current.pem` had been renewed, but *something* was still using an old (and expired) certificate.

Here is how I fixed the issue:

- `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` was obsolete, in particular using `default-user` instead of `system:node:node_name`. I deleted the file, created a kubeadm conf file and ran `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig kubelet` to recreate a clean `kubelet.conf`
- `/var/lib/kublet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem` is supposed to be a symlink, which was not the case for me. So I removed it.
- restart kubelet and apiserver (kill the pod using containerd, docker, etc. since kubectl is unavailable) and wait for a new `kubelet-client-current.pem` to be created ; it should be a symlink.
- run `kubeadm init phase kubelet-finalize all`
- restart kubelet again
- run `kubeadm certs renew all`
- reboot (or restart kubelet and all control plane pods)
- update your kubectl conf from `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

Comment: For anyone interested, the documentation ended up at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#kubelet-client-cert

Answer (score 2):

If you are a user and have a `kubeconfig` file and wanna inspect the `kubeconfig` cert's expiration date you can run this command

```bash
cat <path-to-kubeconfig-file> | grep client-certificate-data | cut -f2 -d : | tr -d ' ' | base64 -d | openssl x509 -text -out - | grep "Not After"
```

Replace your file path with `<path-to-kubeconfig-file>`

If you wanna find out more details about your cert you can print all details with:

```
cat <path-to-kubeconfig-file> | grep client-certificate-data | cut -f2 -d : | tr -d ' ' | base64 -d | openssl x509 -text -out -
```

Comment: My config has `certificate-authority-data` instead of `client-certificate-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues seems to be linked to NTP desynchronization.
Try forcing time synchronization (run as root):

```
# service ntp stop
# ntpd -gq
# service ntp start
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Time was correct, and I resynchronized with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Renew Kubernetes certificates (RUN on all master node)

```
#kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration
#kubeadm init phase kubelet-finalize all
#kubeadm alpha certs renew all
#cd /etc/kubernetes
#kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --org system:nodes --client-name system:node:$(hostname) > kubelet.conf
#mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
#cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
#chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
#restart server
#kubectl get nodes
```